# Retrofit 2 in Android results in Java.io.EOFException when querying items from MongoDB database by Node.js

Tags: java, android, node.js, mongodb, retrofit2

I have been having trouble trying to query multiple MongoDB documents in form of an JSONArray from mLab at once using Retrofit 2 in an Android project. The documents I'm trying to query have the have the same value in one of their fields, so I used the db.collection.find() method in my Node.js API. Here is the android app code.

```
 productSubscription.add(ProductNetworkUtil
     .getProductRetrofit(myToken).getProductByCategory("Hardware")
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .subscribe(this::handleProductListResponse,this::handleProductError));

            private void handleProductResponse(Product product)
            {
                String itemName = product.getItemName();
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.content_home_screen), itemName, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int stop = 0;
            }
            private void handleProductListResponse(JSONArray productList)
            {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.content_home_screen),"Hardware list received",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int stop = 0;
            }
            private void handleProductError(Throwable error)
            {
                if(error instanceof HttpException)
                {
                    Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    try
                    {
                        String errorBody = ((HttpException)error).response().errorBody().string();
                        Response response = gson.fromJson(errorBody,Response.class);
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.content_home_screen),response.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.content_home_screen),"Network Error!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Here is the ProductNetworkUtil class used in the previous snippet,

```
public class ProductNetworkUtil {
public static Retrofit2ProductInterface getProductRetrofit(String token) {

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {

        Request original = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("x-access-token", token)
                .method(original.method(),original.body());
        return  chain.proceed(builder.build());

    });

    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NewLoginConstants.PRODUCT_FETCHER_URL)
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(Retrofit2ProductInterface.class);
}}
```

Here is the Interface class I have been using:

```
enter cpublic interface Retrofit2ProductInterface {

@GET("products/{itemName}")
Observable<Product> getProduct(@Path("itemName") String itemName);

@GET("products/{category}")
Observable<JSONArray> getProductByCategory(@Header("category") String category);}
```

If I were to use the query method using the itemName field as the parameter, I can query successfully since inside the database the itemName for each document is unique. However, the getProductByCategory method results in Java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in the debugger. I have searched for some answers and some say this is due to the app receiving empty data. So I tried to change the node.js code as well.

```
    exports.getProductByCategory = category => 

    new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {

    var productList = product.find({ category: category }, { 
        _id: 1,
        QRCode: 1,
        owner: 1,
        itemName: 1,
        salePrice: 1,
        price: 1,
        sku: 1,
        webCode: 1,
        summary: 1,
        description: 1,
        inTheBox: 1,
        warranty: 1,
        category: 1,
        mainImg: 1,
        otherImgs: 1
     }).toArray();
     product.resolve({productList, message: 'Got your list!'})
    .catch(err => reject({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error !' }))

});
```

Here is the related code from the routes.js of the node.js API

```
'use strict';
```

const detail = require('./functions/detail');
const config = require('./config/config.json');

module.exports = router => {

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.end('This is the product node!'));

router.get('/products/:id', (req,res) => {
        detail.getProduct(req.params.id)
        .then(result => res.json(result))
        .catch(err => res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message }));
});

    router.get('/products/:category', (req,res) => {
    detail.getProductByCategory(req.params.category)
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => res.status(err.status).json({message: err.message}));
});
```

}

I am not sure if the node.js API has some fundamental coding error, or it is the android query method that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything because I would need more info and check it by myself (your response data).

Did you try to debug / log and check what is the response content? It looks that it's wrong.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain yet but I think I found the main issue. I was not aware the routes inside my Node.js API had to be in an specific order of first come first serve. So every time the getProductByCategory query is called, express actually run the getProduct lines. I found out this using the Chrome debugger of Visual Studio Code. The breakpoints ingetProductByCategory were never triggered while the breakpoints in the getProduct were always triggered. Now all that's left is to find a way to resolve a promise in the form of an JSONarray so my android app can receive it successfully. Thank you.